# p:media does not work in FireFox, but it works in Chrome and Opera

Tags: pdf, firefox, primefaces

p:media component does not work in FireFox, but it works in Chrome and Opera.
I'm trying to display a PDF document, but nothing is displayed in FireFox.
Although the component in the tutorial is displayed for me: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/multimedia/media.xhtml

```xml
<p:media value="/resources/pdf/mypdf.pdf" width="100%" height="600px">
     Your browser can't display pdf, 
     <h:outputLink value="/resources/pdf/mypdf.pdf">click</h:outputLink> to download pdf instead.         
</p:media>
```

Comment: What version of PrimeFaces are you using?

Comment: 7.0, I tried 6.2, same problem

Comment: Any errors on the browser console?

Comment: Firefox version?

Comment: No erros, version is 69.0.3